# After Effects/ Photoshop GIF animation stops looping

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-after-effects

I rendered an animation from After Effects via Adobe Media Encoder as an MP4 file and opened it in Photoshop to export as a GIF. This worked, but the GIF stops looping after 3 loops. It's endless in AE and Photoshop. Any idea why the final product doesn't loop forever?

The GIF is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ed2oo2jog4m8toe/Earth-and-astronaut_1.gif?dl=0

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Photoshop will only import the first 500 frames of a video.**

If your video is more than 500 frames, you need to perform **multiple imports** - Frames 1-500, then frames 501-1000, then frames 1001-1500, etc. Once you've imported the frames, you can move the video layers to a single document and reconstruct the timeline.

That gif is 500 frames....

That gif is set to play **once**. You need to set to `Forever` in the **Timeline Panel** or the **Save For Web Dialog** if you want the gif to  loop.

The loop the gif is performing can be done less than **half** the frames. You only need to astronaut to pass once... then repeat.

A **~4.8MB** gif is **ridiculously** huge in terms of size.

.. shrunk to 300px... and only 224 frames.. looping.... (580k)

[image]

Unless there's some other animation which I can't see in your gif, this would be sufficient.

If you keep the original size (1080px).. the resulting 224 frame, looped, gif is 2.4MB in size. Which is still quite large.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the quick response. How do I reduce the number of frames–should that be done in After Effects?

Comment: You can delete frames in Photoshop using the Timeline Panel. If it's a frame animation, select the frames and hit the delete icon on the panel. If it's a timeline animation, trim the video after the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Got it. I exported at 300px and it is working. Thanks so much! I'm new to this process and appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this issue by using a free script AEJuice Export GIF to export directly from After Effects. Just make sure the size works for you, it might be pretty big.

By default, it is looped "Forever" so it should resolve your problem of playing only once in Photoshop.

You can play around with quality settings to reduce the size or use your own After Effects preset with less quality.